# How to find out easily whether a block device (or a part of it) is mounted somehow

Tags: linux, mount, proc, block-device, sysfs

I want to know what the easiest way is to determine (without root privilege) whether a block device (say `sdb`) or any part of it is mounted (and which part of it).

Checking `/proc/mounts` for sdb is not enough because `sdb` or one of its partitions may be used by LVM. You can check `/sys/block/sdb/sdb*/holders/` but you get `dm-x` entries which have to be resolved to `/dev/mapper` names in order to check `/proc/mounts`. Possible but if there is an easier solution... (which should not require root privilege)

Comment: I'm curious, were you not just trying to find out if the device is mounted?  */holders and */*/holders is good enough to tell you its mounted if the device doesn't exist in the /proc/mounts table.  Why do you need to resolve it, further?  i.e. cryptsetup adds it to the holders, indicating you shouldn't be messing with the drive.. even if the /dev/mapper isn't mount, or cause encryption corruption.  Its just that its being mounted internally through a driver.  Also don't forget to check /sys/block/sdb/holders as well, as the drive could be "held" without partitions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is essentially a matter of checking a whole bag of corner cases.

- A drive can appear in /proc/mounts
- A drive can be used as swap *(use /proc/swaps)*
- A drive can be part of an active LVM pv *(use pvdisplay)*
- A drive can be part of a dm-mapper RAID group *(use /proc/mdstat)*
- A drive can be directly accessed by an application (e.g. Oracle supports writing directly to a drive or partition instead of a filesystem) *(use fuser)*
- A drive can be directly accessed by a virtual machine *(use fuser)*
- A drive can be referenced by a loopback device (e.g: `mount /dev/sda -o offset=1M /foo`) *(use losetup -a)*

These are just the examples I came up with given a minute and a half to think about it. I'm sure there's a dozen others.

This last example I think is the most interesting and few people know about it. It allows you to mount a filesystem without using partitions. Just specify the starting offset and Linux will transparently create a loopback device. The example above yields the following:

```
# cat /proc/mounts
...
/dev/loop0 /foo ext4 relatime,data=ordered 0 0

# losetup -a
/dev/loop0 [0005]:2048 (/dev/sda), offset 1048576
```

Why would you do that? Typically it involves situations where things have previously gone horribly wrong.

Also bear in mind that with the namespacing feature now in mainline (see [unshare](http://linux.die.net/man/2/unshare)), different processes can have different views about what's mounted and what isn't. Here things start to get a little bit red-pill.

Answer (score 1):

There is much more ways to mount devices, all of them can be combined, so it's like often, up to you to find out.

i.e. what's used by lvm: `pvdisplay`

So you need include also nfs, cifs, raid, loop, crypt, and so on.
A good starting point is always `/proc/mounts`, as you have already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

For device-mapper devices at least (which include cryptsetup and LVM volumes), there is the "Open count" displayed by `dmsetup info`.  It comes from the `DM_TABLE_STATUS` ioctl and also appears to be the basis of the `o` (open) flag shown by `lvs`.  That seems to be pretty comprehensive: for example, in dom0 of my Qubes OS 4.0 system (based on Fedora 25), it detected use by `xen_blkback`, which isn't mentioned by any of the other answers here or detected by `lsblk`.

Unfortunately, in brief research, I couldn't find an analogue of this for arbitrary block devices.