How can I resolve this error: "mdadm: Cannot open /dev/sd*: Device or resource busy" when adding a replacement drive to RAID5?
I have a RAID5 with 4 drives, looks like this:
[root@g1016637 ~]# mdadm -D /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Mar  8 16:35:25 2023
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 23441682432 (21.83 TiB 24.00 TB)
     Used Dev Size : 7813894144 (7.28 TiB 8.00 TB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Fri Jun 14 09:33:02 2024
             State : clean, degraded
    Active Devices : 3
   Working Devices : 3
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : raid5:data
              UUID : 0fca8296:53b5287c:f3cd71c9:38a2c1b5
            Events : 1126730

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        0        0      active sync   /dev/sda
       1       8       16        1      active sync   /dev/sdb
       -       0        0        2      removed
       4       8       48        3      active sync   /dev/sdd

I'm trying to add a replacement drive:
[root@g1016637 ~]# mdadm /dev/md127 -a /dev/sdc
mdadm: Cannot open /dev/sdc: Device or resource busy

I've tried to stop the main array but I'm a bit concerned:
[root@g1016637 ~]# mdadm --stop /dev/md127
mdadm: Cannot get exclusive access to /dev/md127:Perhaps a running process, mounted filesystem or active volume group?

I tried unmounting my array and getting this:
[root@g1016637 ~]# umount /dev/md127
umount: /mnt/library: target is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))

Just seems super strange. I'd like to do this without rebooting the unit if possible.

It's in use somehow - ideas on where to look for e.g. here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111779/30851
